# Which test can I use to compare two count data means with a lot of zeros?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean, count-data, zero-inflation

Suppose I have two count datasets, lets say the count of tigers across different years at two places. Now for most of the years we have 0 tiger sightings. For eg.

```
* Years Place   no._of_sightings
* 2007  Corbett 0
* 2007  Gir     0
* 2008  Corbett 1
* 2008  Gir     0
* 2009  Corbett 0
* 2009  Gir     4
* 2010  Corbett 0
* 2010  Gir     0
* 2011  Corbett 2
* 2011  Gir     1
* 2012  Corbett 0
* 2012  Gir     0
* 2013  Corbett 0
* 2013  Gir     0
* 2014  Corbett 2
* 2014  Gir     0
* 2015  Corbett 0
* 2015  Gir     1
```

Now for such data which test shall I perform if I want to  test the hypothesis that the mean values of the measurement variable are the same in two groups. As the data has a lot of zeros and not normal, we cannot use t-test. Kindly suggest an appropriate test.

Comment: [This article](https://www.kent.ac.uk/smsas/personal/msr/webfiles/zip/ibc_fin.pdf) may be of interest